# Adding Polynomials with exponents. Can't get same answer as answer key.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This question is from my final practice exam.

simplify and express each answer using positive exponents only.
$$(2x^3y^{-2}z^0)^2+8x^{-3}y^2 $$

After working out the problem this is the answer that I get.
$$\frac{4x^6+8y^2}{y^4x^3}$$

However, the answer key says,
$$\frac{x^9}{2y^6}$$

Can someone explain, thanks.

Comment: Neither of these are correct.  Yours is closer but the numerator ought to be $4x^9+8y^6$

Comment: How did you add the exponents?

Comment: it looks like the answer key is simplifying $(2x^3y^{-2}z^0)^2 \div 8x^{-3}y^2$, instead

Comment: I think so too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer key is wrong, but your answer is almost correct.  You accidentally multiplied the denominators without making equivalent fractions.
It should instead look like $$\frac{4x^6}{y^4}+\frac{8y^2}{x^3}$$  You can then cross-multiply to get the correct numerator. $$\frac{4x^9+8y^6}{y^4x^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's simplified:

$\left(2x^3y^{-2}z^0\right)^2 + 8x^{-3}y^2 = \dfrac{4x^6}{y^4} + \dfrac{8y^2}{x^3} = \dfrac{4x^9+8y^6}{x^3y^4}$

The answer key can't be right. If you plug in $x=1$ and $y=1$ (and $z$ can be anything but $0$), the original expression becomes $4+8$, while the purported answer becomes $\dfrac12$. What was intended there is really anyone's guess.